# How to handle login success in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

Apologies if my question seems like something a novice would ask. I am new to the Spring world. I am using Spring Security to authenticate users. Authentication is working properly, but after authentication success I want Spring to call the Controller method .`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public JwtAuthenticationResponse userLogin() {
System.out.println("Login Success");
        JwtUser user = (JwtUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String token = userService.generateToken(authenticationService.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername()));
        JwtAuthenticationResponse response = new JwtAuthenticationResponse(token, user.getAuthorities().toArray(),user.getUsername());
        return response;
    }
}
```

In Spring Security Configuration I added the following

```
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/login");

http.addFilterBefore(filter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

In this case, it is returning a default Spring Login form. It is not calling my controller method.

I made the request using

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/login
```

Can someone suggest what I have to do to invoke the Controller after login is successful, in order to send the Authentication token after login.

Appreciate any help!

Thank you

Comment: @Ankit I am not using any security configuration xml file. I extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and configured in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer. I am using Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are providing your custom controller for login then just remove following

```
.formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/login")
```

From `httpSecurity` configuration. And this will remove spring security's default login page.

or you can follow : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html

Comment: I am not using controller for user validation. I am trying to use Spring security for user validation and if it is successful I want to invoke the controller for sending the response back.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake I was doing. I need not declare request mapping for login. I realized that Spring will take care of it.